# Not finding DirectX namespace anymore

Tags: c++, windows, directx

Visual Studio Professional 2013

Windows 7

x32, x64 processor

I am using DirectX 11 and seem to be having a weird problem.  I have always been able to access the DirectX namespace in my application.  This is no longer the case.  I can make a simple class say

```
// A.h

#include <d3d11.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")

class A {

}
```

If I try to use a fully referenced type

`DirectX::ID3D11Device* mDevice;`

I don't get the DirectX namespace showing up with intellisense as I used too.

And to top it all off I can use

```
ID3D11Device* device;
```

in the class with no problem and all compiles well.

The path where Visual Studio 2013 Profesional is finding the d3d11.h file is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
```

Any idea why this could be happening?  I have searched many places but have found nothing of the same nature.

Comment: I found my mistake.  Sorry about the post.  The DirectX namespace is included with DirectXMath.h not d3d11.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Windows Win32 APIs are in the 'global' namespace.

The `DirectX` C++ namespace is used by [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx), [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926), and [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981). Basically everything I'm the author for :)

There are a few helpers in the `DX` C++ namespace that is used in the standard VS templates for Windows 8 Store, Windows phone, Xbox One, and universal Windows apps for Windows 10 for [StepTimer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/12/03/understanding-game-time-revisited.aspx) and `ThrowIfFailed`, which is also used in my unofficial [Windows desktop VS template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs are in a standard `Windows` or `Microsoft` C++ namespace following the naming convention originally created for .NET components.